# ctrl+c in VSCode

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, localserver

I am working on a Django project at the moment and usually to stop the local server from running I press ctrl+c. However, a few days ago this stopped working. I think an extension or a VSCode update has caused this. Does anyone know how I can reset this keyboard shortcut in VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reset the keyboard shortcuts if it's caused by a vscode update, but you can simply edit the keyboard shortcuts by yourself. To do this, you can open it with the keyboard shortcut CTRL+K CTRL+S or just click on the settings in the bottom left corner of the vscode window and there will be keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: So ive gone to Code > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts. Here i can create and remove any keyboard shortcut, but in the whole list i cant see anything for stop local server from running?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).